# Measuring DevOps KPIs like Deployment Speed, Deployment Failure Rate and Time to Recover with AzureDevops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-analytics

I'm trying to create an Azure DevOps dashboard for a project with below KPIs.

- Lead Time
- Deployment Speed
- Deployment Failure rate
- Time to recover

These KPIs are not available in Azure DevOps by default except for the Lead Time. Azure DevOps Analytics also doesn't support it yet. However, similar KPIs are available when we check build analytics. Is there anyway to achieve this now or do we have to wait till  Azure DevOps analytics support this? Or else is it possible with oData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, some KPIs are not supported in Azure DevOps Analytics as you think.

You could submit a suggestion ticket to suggest the new feature through this url: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 directly.

After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Comment: Thanks Hugh Lin for clarification. I'll submit a ticket as you have suggested. Hopefully Azure DevOps will expose pipeline data soon.